# Does a Docker image built in x86_64 work when pulled in aarch64/s390x?

Tags: docker, arm, x86-64, cpu-architecture, s390x

If I run `docker build` on a `x86_64/amd64` Linux, and then save the resulting image as a `.tar` file via `docker save`, and then place it on another Linux machine which is `aarch64/arm64`, will it work normally there (after `docker load` and `docker run`)? Also, what if the second machine is `s390x` (IBM Z) instead of `aarch64/arm64`?

Comment: One processor can't normally run binaries built for another; their instruction set architectures are different.

Answer (score 0):

You can do docker run by passing specific platform setup

```bash
docker run --platform linux/amd64
```

Not always working, But it is indeed a trick way sometimes.

Comment: How does this work?  Does it use QEMU to emulate the foreign binaries?